# Install4j - is there any finalization stage option in case of a failure?

Tags: java, install4j

We are using Install4j 6.1.6. On the installer, one of the *failure strategies* action options is `Quit on failure`.

When marking the option, the installer will try to roll-back previous changes, but won't always be able to. An example for that scenario is when the installer installs a window service, but it won't be able to uninstall it properly by the roll-back in case of a failure later on.

Is there any way defining a 'finally' step, in which I can define what should happens in case if a failure?

**EDIT**: I know there is a "*Rollback executable*" property on the "*Run executable or batch file*" action, but it still won't resolve my problem, since I have many actions which could fail after the service installation. Is there any way defining such a property on a batch of actions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no action blocks that run in case of a rollback.

The best option may be to use "Run script" actions that have just `true` as their script and use their "Optional Rollback Script" property to perform cleanup.

If you need the functionality of actions in the rollback code, you can instantiate the actions and execute them programmatically, like this:

```
import com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.misc.RunExecutableAction;

RunExecutableAction action = new RunExecutableAction();
action.setExecutable(...);
action.setArguments(...);

action.execute(context);
```

Comment: This could be working, but this action lacks some important configuration which exists on "Run executable or batch file" action, like "Wait for termination" property. Will it work with "Run executable or batch file" action as well?

Comment: Thanks you! just small question - why do you prefer "run Script" over "Run executable or batch file"  action?
If I already have some logic over the last, why creating another new action instead using the exiting one?

Comment: In the "Run script" action, there is a "Optional Rollback Script" property that is called during a rollback. The "Run executable or batch file" action has a "Use rollback executable" property, but no way to execute code during a rollback.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for me. I guess I did something wrong.
 The "Run script" action's "Optional Rollback Script" doesn't getting perform during a rollback. I configured another previous action to fail in purpose (Quit on failure), but the rollback script won't do anything.. Am I missing anything?

Comment: The "Run script" action would have to be before the action that produces the failure and there must not be any action or screen in between that is marked as a rollback barrier,